# WPF Changing DataGrid Row Background Colour if JobTimeStart Column is 1 hour away from JobTimeFinish Column

Tags: c#, wpf

In my database **"JobTimeStart"** and **"JobTimeFinish"** are both stored as **'Time'** Datatypes. I need the row background colour to change to red in my DataGrid if **"JobTimeStart"** is 1 hour away from **"JobTimeFinish"**.

I made a trigger for my **"JobDate"** column so that if it matches todays date it will change colour to orange. I have been trying to see if I could maybe do it the same way using triggers, but have had no luck finding anything similar to what I want.

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding JobDate.Date}" Value="{x:Static System:DateTime.Today}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#ff8d00"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

..

```
 <DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Job" Binding="{Binding JobType}"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Path=JobDate, StringFormat=\{0:dd/MM/yyyy\}}" x:Name="JobDate"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Start Time" Binding="{Binding JobTimeStart}"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Finish Time" Binding="{Binding JobTimeFinish}" x:Name="JobTimeFinish"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Anything to help push me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If those properties are never to be changed, you can bind the trigger to the data item itself, rather than the DateProperty and then use a converter to check whether those properties match the predicate. However, if those are changed at run-time, the data trigger would not be notified:

```
 <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding, Converter={StatocResource SomeConverter}}" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#ff8d00"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```

If using triggers is not a requirement, I would use the [RowStyleSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowstyleselector?view=netframework-4.8) feature.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to subtract times and compare the result to a pre-defined `TimeSpan` in XAML.

What you should to is to add a property to your view model or model that returns a value that indicates whether `Background` property should be set in the view:

```
public bool Warn => JobTimeFinish.Subtract(JobTimeStart).TotalHours >= 1;
```

You can then trigger on this property:

```
 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Warn}" Value="True">
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
 </DataTrigger>
```

This way you also keep your logic in your view model or model where it belongs and can be tested separately. XAML is a *markup* language.